# FPRAS for approximating eigenvalues of graph Laplacians

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Is there a [fully polynomial-time randomized approximation scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme) (FPRAS) to approximate the eigenvalues (or even the largest one) of graph Laplacians?

By FPRAS, I mean the algorithm runs in time $\mbox{poly} \left( n, \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right)$ for an $\epsilon$-approximation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You have mentionned in your tags "graph Laplacian". This should be in your text as well because usually a Laplacian is in the context of analysis.

Comment: About dominant eigenvalues, it depends if their moduli are well separated of not...